# Postgres: is there an exhaustive list of causes that make `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` end in an `INVALID` state?

Tags: postgresql, postgres15

Besides these potential, [documented](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY) causes:

- a deadlock
- hitting `statement_timeout`
- for a unique index: a uniqueness violation
- for expression and partial indexes: expression evaluation errors

1. Are there more?
2. How could a `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` statement, with its [SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/explicit-locking.html#LOCKING-TABLES)  lock, end up in a deadlock, mentioned in the documentation above?
3. Is `lock_timeout` actually *needed*, when `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` is the only DDL statement to be run? **Isn't it ok to just 'wait it out' until the lock is acquired, as the statement won't be blocking regular CRUD operations anyway.** I can only think of one problematic scenario: if the incoming data distribution varies enough that not running `ANALYZE` (which would be blocked) would impact the planner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How to cause a deadlock with `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`:

Session 1:

```
CREATE TABLE tab (id integer);
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (1);
```

Session 2:

```
-- this will hang
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY ON tab (id);
```

Session 3:

```
-- this will hang
ALTER TABLE tab ADD col2 integer;
```

Session 1:

```
-- this will hang
ALTER TABLE tab ADD col3 integer;
```

On my PostgreSQL v16, the deadlock detector will cancel sessions 1 and 2.

#### The exhaustive list when `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` will fail:

This is a fool's errand. You will never be able to enumerate all possible causes. Let me give you a few to show how pointless the exercise is:

- `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` hits `lock_timeout`
- the database server crashes due to hardware failure
- the network connection gets interrupted
- the server runs out of disk space

Any other runtime error will serve.

To be honest, I don't see the point behind that question. When you run `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`, you check if it succeeds or not. If not, drop the invalid index. Alternatively, if you are in the habit of creating indexes frequently, schedule a regular job that gets rid of all invalid indexes.

Comment: For the deadlock part, I though presume that concurrent DMLs, rather than DDLs, aren't problematic. 

For the 'external' possible causes  (f.e. disk, network, etc.), agreed. Was more interested about PG-internal scenarios, f.e. the `lock_timeout` you listed: curious if there are more. Also curious, **is `lock_timeout` actually _needed_ when `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` is the sole DDL operation?** Please see the added question 3.

Comment: `lock_timeout` is not needed. I was trying to give you a taste of possible causes for the statement to fail. As I said, there are many more. Don't try to find them all, you won't succeed.